# Can magnetic fields can be directed along a ray far outside their emitter?

Tags: electromagnetism

Electric fields can be masked, but without the perfection of recent technology, the same can't be said for magnetic fields. So, is there an arrangement of magnetic materials that can direct many magnetic field lines to a point or general cylindrical region that extends well past the surface of whatever is generating the magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible for *static* magnetic fields.  The field lines always get weaker with greater distance from the source.  The same is true of static electric fields.  Radio waves and other electromagnetic waves (which are not static) can be focused, though.

Comment: But a moving magnetic field is just an electric field again...

Comment: It's not quite that simple.   A changing magnetic field *induces* an electric field, and a changing electric field *induces* a magnetic field.  It's all in Maxwell's equations.

Comment: So you're saying if you simply physically move magnets around or translate them, then you can focus their lines?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that.  I'm saying that electromagnetic waves can be focused.